# Split an Iterator containing two foreach loops in two different functions

Tags: c#, iterator, generator, yield-return

I have the current function:

```
private IEnumerable<string> GetKeysStringValues(RegistryKey key)
{
    foreach (var subKey in GetAllSubKeys(key))
    {
        foreach (var value in subKey.GetValueNames())
        {
            if (subKey.GetValueKind(value) == RegistryValueKind.String)
            {
                yield return (string) subKey.GetValue(value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It:

1. Parse all subkeys of a registry key
2. For each subkeys, parse all of its values
3. If the value is a string, adds it to the iterator

My concern is that there's two embedded for-each loops, which I do not like at all.
I'd like to split this function in two.

The problem is that I end up in the end with a return type of `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>`

I tried to build the Iterator in the second function only, and directly return it in the first, but doing this I miss all the subsequent calls.

This is the code that caused it:

```
    private IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> GetSubKeysStringValues(RegistryKey key)
    {
        IEnumerable<string> enumerable = Enumerable.Empty<string>();
        
        foreach (var subKey in GetAllSubKeys(key))
        {
            yield return GetKeysStringValues(subKey));
        }
    }

    private IEnumerable<string> GetKeysStringValues(RegistryKey key)
    {
        foreach (var value in key.GetValueNames())
        {
            if (key.GetValueKind(value) == RegistryValueKind.String)
            {
                yield return (string) key.GetValue(value);
            }
        }
    }
```

How would you do that ?

Edit:

I have this solution so far, but could it be improved ?

```
private IEnumerable<string> GetSubKeysStringValues(RegistryKey key)
{
    IEnumerable<string> enumerable = Enumerable.Empty<string>();
    
    foreach (var subKey in GetAllSubKeys(key))
    {
        enumerable = enumerable.Concat(GetKeysStringValues(subKey));
    }

    return enumerable;
}

private IEnumerable<string> GetKeysStringValues(RegistryKey key)
{
    foreach (var value in key.GetValueNames())
    {
        if (key.GetValueKind(value) == RegistryValueKind.String)
        {
            yield return (string) key.GetValue(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with two foreach? You should also show what caused a `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>`.

Comment: Two foreach are way harder to unit test and in this case does not respect SRP

Comment: I uploaded the code as you requested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have this solution so far, but could it be improved ?

Your solution is fine. If you want more compact code, you can use the LINQ method `SelectMany`, whose purpose is to "flatten" an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>` into an `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
private IEnumerable<string> GetSubKeysStringValues(RegistryKey key)
{
    return GetAllSubKeys(key).SelectMany(subKey => GetKeysStringValues(subKey));
}
```

...or, if you prefer query syntax (yields the same result and probably even the same IL code):

```
private IEnumerable<string> GetSubKeysStringValues(RegistryKey key)
{
    return from subKey in GetAllSubKeys(key)
           from value in GetKeysStringValues(subKey)
           select value;
}
```

Comment: I like that one ! Now, I would like to call a function on each of the returned results, and do it via a LINQ query. It's not working so far, I can do it only with a foreach loop

Comment: @Zangdar: Do you mean something like `from x in returnedResults select myFunction(x)`?

Comment: yes. When doing this, I have this error: The type arguments for method 'IEnumerable<TResult> System.Linq.Enumerable.Select<TSource,TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource,TResult>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: @Zangdar: Does myFunction return a value? If no, that's not really suitable for LINQ, since linq is a query language. If yes, I suggest you create a new question with a [mcve].

Comment: It does not, it's a function that provides a copy service. I am used to Python comprehension but I guess then that in this case there's no equivalent and I should rely on the foreach loop

Comment: @Zangdar: Well, there is `List<T>.ForEach(Action<T> action)`, but, to be honest, a plain old foreach loop is perfectly fine here.

Comment: You can shorten to `SelectMany(GetKeysStringValues)` using a method group, but some do not like that syntax